# How to delay firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening(); , that needs to start at onStart?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a firebaseRecyclerAdapter in my activity.

THe firebase node it needs to listen to, is created by a click on the activity.

Since it starts at onStart, and the node is not yet created, it crashes.

Is there a way to overcome this?

**EDIT 1**
since my code is terribly messy, I'll try to explain it here.
On activity launch, a button is "BEGIN CHAT". On click, it creates a child in node "Users", with uid , which also has a child "currentChatId".
In case the child in exists, it only updates the "currentChatId"

This currentChatId, updates every time user starts a new chat session

Now in "messages" node, each message child has a child "chatId" ,
and the firebaseRecyclerAdapter queries for

```
 databaseReferenceM.orderByChild("chatId").equalTo(currentChatIssueKey)
```

currentChatIssueKey is the same as chatId.

And firebaseRecyclerAdapter needs this

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

    }
```

This said node in "messages", is meant to be created when the user first sends a message.

Since that node does not exist at "onStart", the app crashes

Comment: please share the codes?

Comment: Recommend sharing the code.

Comment: But basically, In your onStart(), you can try to get() the data at the firebase node, or set a listener.  If it is empty, then do not call firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening().  If it is not empty, then call firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening().  

Then, in your activity onClickListener, you can do:

firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

Comment: @Ekrem I hope the the edit works. Or else, I'll add the code too.

Comment: @JeffPadgett, I'll try that, thanks

Comment: @JeffPadgett I tried using the firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening(), at the send button click listener, but then it reloads the entrie view after every message, and it looks bad on-screen

Comment: Ok, you can add a protection in the button Click Listener in the same way, so... if the data at the node already exists, you know that onStart() has already called .startListening(), and you do not need to call  .startListening() in the onClick anymore.  Something like: 

if (dataAtFirebaseNode == empty) {  create data at node, adapter.startListening()} 
else { update data at node}